# how to trigger an animation after another ends

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to trigger jQuery animation after another one ends.

Here is what first happens , this is a slide down tot he second navigationbar:

```
$(".navigation-bar1").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".navigation-bar2").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
});
```

Second animation , this triggers a css that opens a navigationbar :

```
$(".trigger-navbar").click(function() {
    $("body").toggleClass("navbar-down");
});
```

Comment: I'm confused as the 'second animation' is just adding a class to an element which is done under a completely separate event...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the [official documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) you can read that the signature of `animate()` is

```
.animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
```

`[, complete]` is the part you are interested in: you can write a function that will be called when the animation ends.

Therefore, in your case you can try:

```
$(".navigation-bar1").click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".navigation-bar2").offset().top
    }, 
    'slow', 
    function(){
        // This will be executed after the animation ends
        $("body").toggleClass("navbar-down");
    });
});
```

Comment: It should toggle the class on the selector correctly. I created a small example, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/L11bz2kq/4/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `queue()` function (assuming that 'trigger-navbar' and 'navigation-bar1' are classes of the same element):

```
$(".navigation-bar1").click(function() {
  $('html,body').animate({
     scrollTop: $(".navigation-bar2").offset().top},'slow')
     .queue(function() {
        $("body").toggleClass("navbar-down");
        $(this).dequeue();
     });
});
```

Comment: The second 'toggleClass' thing :P doesn't work anymore now..??

Answer (score 0):

you can trigger a new animation in complete callback function

> .animate( properties [, duration ] [, easing ] [, complete ] )
>   complete
>
> > Type: Function()
> >     A function to call once the animation is complete.

Answer (score 0):

From [jQuery's documentation](http://api.jquery.com/animate/), animate() takes a callback function. This function will be executed after the animation completes.

```
  $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".navigation-bar2").offset().top
  }, 'slow', function() {
    // Animation complete, do something else
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `animate()`-function supports a complete-callback:

```
$(".navigation-bar1").click(function() {
    $('html').animate({
        scrollTop: $(".navigation-bar2").offset().top
    }, 'slow', function(){
        $("body").toggleClass("navbar-down");
        // OR
        $(".trigger-navbar").click();
   });
});
```

[.animate()](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

**[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/c8Lyfm77/)**

Comment: Neither here toggles it the class

Comment: @WesselVisser because of the `html, body`-selector the complete callback will trigger twice, so the class gets removed again. Try to change your selector to `html` only, see my example

Answer (score 0):

Both animate trigger with click?

```
$(".navigation-bar1").click(function() {
$('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(".navigation-bar2").offset().top
}, 'slow');

 $(".trigger-navbar").click()
});
```